# Encapsulating a JNI library inside a jar file

Tags: cmake, java-native-interface, imagej

I am trying to develop a plugin for Fiji/ImageJ that relies on a native library (JNI).
The JNI library itself depends on `libtiff` and `fftw`. On OSX and Linux, I use the class [NativeUtils](https://github.com/adamheinrich/native-utils) and everything works fine.

On windows, I included binary versions of `libtiff` and `fftw` in the `CMake` package and managed to link the JNI library against those (either statically of dynamically). However, the resulting JNI module does not include `libtiff` or `fftw` and I obtain an error when I try to load the JNI library with `NativeUtils.loadLibraryFromJar`. This is also the case when I include the dependent `.dll` in the `.jar` since they are not extracted by `NativeUtils`.

Here are the relevant lines in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(fftw STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(fftw PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${libdir}/libfftw3f-3.lib"
                                      INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES  "${incdir}")

SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(javainterf
                 TYPE MODULE
                 LANGUAGE java
                 SOURCES javainterf.i javainterf.c src1.c)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(javainterf libcode1 fftw)

add_jar(Foo
        SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/java/foo1.java
        INCLUDE_JARS java/resources/ij-1.51p.jar
        VERSION ${JAR_VERSION})
add_dependencies(Foo javainterf)
add_custom_command(TARGET Foo POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE}" -uf Foo-${JAR_VERSION}.jar
    -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR} ${JNI_LIB_NAME})
```

How would you make sure that all the dependencies are properly included in the jar and loaded?

Comment: Not a full solution, but have you read the [Developing using native libraries](https://imagej.net/Developing_using_native_libraries) page of the ImageJ documentation? Have you tried placing your native library in `$IJ_ROOT/lib/<platform>` instead of embedding within a JAR file?

Comment: I thought about it but it makes the install more complicated for the end user. I'll try to go with including everything in the jar works if the solution proposed by @mko works for me.

Comment: I do not understand your concern about installation. If you use an [update site](https://imagej.net/Update_Sites) you can ship all your needed files to the user with the click of a button on their end, and they'll receive updates automatically, too.

Comment: @ctrueden I just didn't know about this. I'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load library from inside JAR without extracting it in a first place.

Take a look here at full sample where native code is embedded inside JAR and extracted when needed.

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo031

**Update**

Well, in that case, when you need to pack more libs and you want to properly resolve locations, you need to play with runtime env a little bit.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo035

```
git clone https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook
cd jnicookbook/recipes/recipeNo035
make
make test
```

Have fun with JNI!

Comment: The problem here is that I have several dependent libraries and only one get extracted at a time. I don't see how to merge all the dependencies into one dll with cmake.

Comment: You can always extract all the libraries and load all of them using System.load. After all, it's just all about symbols that are loaded from libs.

Comment: My jni library depends on some non-jni shared libraries. Even though they are not jni, I tried to load them with `loadlibraryfromjar`, and it does not work: I get the very same error.

Comment: I haven't have time to test your solution yet. But thanks for taking the time to write an additional recipe for me. I'll accept your answer as soon as I have a chance to test it. Thanks

Comment: > "You can't load library from inside JAR without extracting it in a first place."  what do you mean by this ? I just put my DLL in the .jar and it works fine (with JNA)

Comment: com/sun/jna/Native.java -> extractFromResourcePath

Comment: You can load library from inside jar